# Angular 6: Unit test an async file import with Karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, asynchronous, karma-runner

basically, I am trying to unit test my asynchronous file import function with Karma but somehow I can't get it to work.

Assume I have the following function to import a file . A user clicks on a button which therefore opens up the operating systems file dialog. A user then selects the to be imported file and presses ok.

> 1. Read a file and store it in the Backend

```
public handleTheProcess(event){
  // set this.file with a selected file
  this.file = <File>event.type.target.files[0];
  this.sendFileToBackend(this.file);
}

public sendFileToBackend(file: File){
  if(file){

   // create a FormData obj since the file comes from a MultiPart file
   const formData = new FormData();
   formData.append( // append the file...);

   // send file to the backend via a POST reqest
   this.http.post(...)
    .subscribe( event => { // Do some status checks..
      return true;
    }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        return false;
      });
  } else {
     // something unexpected happend
     return false;
   }
```

In order to test it, I tried this:

> Unit test to test the import function

```
// basic configureTestSuite configs generated by Angular itself
// ...
//...
describe("Request should return true because we pass a valid file", () => {
  fit("return false", fakeAsync(() => {
    event = {};
    event.target = {};
    event.target.files = [];

    event.target.files.push( new File(["Excel file content"], "Mock.xlsx", { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" }));

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", event.target.files[0], event.target.files[0].name);

    // import the mocked file
    const result = component.sendFileToBackend(event.target.files[0]);
    httpMock.expectOne(...).flush(formData, {status: 200, statusText: "Okayo"});
    tick();
    expect(result).toBeTruthy();
  }));
}
```

What am I missing? 
AFAIK, `result` becomes true since I pass a valid parameter. But `expec(result).toBeTruthy()` fails for some reason.

Please let me know if you need further information.

Any help is appreciated.

Best,
Big Dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This test will never succeed because the function `sendFileToBackend()` never returns true.  The only place you have a `return true` statement inside the function is within a subscribe, which will only be a return of true for the function it is in, not the outer `sendFileToBackend()`.

Your editor should pick up on this fact for you.  Try defining a return value for your function like this:

```
public sendFileToBackend(file: File): boolean {
/* rest of function */
```

Your editor should complain that you are not returning a boolean value from the function as coded.